# angular2 ngModel with value from @Input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm trying to use [(ngModel)] within my child-component with a string passed from my parent into my child component via @Input().

However the two-way-binding does not seem to work. The string gets passed in from the parent correctly, but when I edit it in the child the parent's value does not get updated.

What am I missing?

Parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <child [(value)]="name"></child>
      <p>{{name}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string = 'MyValue';
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Child

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
    <p>My custom input</p>
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="value"></textarea>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child {


  @Input() value:string;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

I created a plnkr which illustrates the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/jCF5kt73P38EFYUAZF6l

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an output to notify about changes:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
    <p>My custom input</p>
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="update($event)"></textarea>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child {


  @Input() value:string;
  @Output() valueChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<String>()

  update(value) {
    this.valueChange.emit(value);
  }

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah - @Input only works one way. When the parent changes the value of Input the child gets notified. However the parent is unaware of any changes to the child, if you are *only* using @Input.

Comment: my bad, i accidentally downvoted your anwser. please make any minor edit so that i can cancel my downvote. Sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to @Günter Zöchbauer answer I have modified the app.ts file as well.

app.ts:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Child} from './child'
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <child [value]="name" (valueChange)= "updateValue($event)"></child>
      <p>{{name}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string = 'MyValue';
  constructor() {

  }
   updateValue(value){
      this.name = value;
    }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, Child ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Child

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
    <p>My custom input</p>
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="update($event)"></textarea>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child {


  @Input() value:string;
 @Output() valueChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<String>();

  constructor() {

  }

  update(value) {
    this.valueChange.emit(value);
  }
}
```